# How to make visible ImageView in click EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new for android . I want to make ImageView visible on click of EditText

```
public void clickHandler(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.orderQty){
        System.out.println(" edit text click");
        System.out.println(" edit text id    dilshad : "+v.getId());
        int id = v.getId();
        id = R.id.save_on_id;
        System.out.println("save button id on button click     : "+id);
        int rew = id;
        v.setId(id);
        System.out.println("save button set  and get id      : "+ v.getId());
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v; 
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.save_on);
        imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

This is my xml for Edittext

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/orderQty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:onClick="clickHandler" >
</EditText>
```

and this ImageView in same xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/save_on_id"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/separator_bottom"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:onClick="clickHandler"
    android:src="@drawable/save_on" />
```

But i am getting Exception ,

```
02-05 16:01:51.969: W/dalvikvm(10554): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at com.example.demoekot.MainScreen.clickHandler(MainScreen.java:491)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    ... 11 more
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
02-05 16:01:51.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10554):    ... 15 more
02-05 16:01:55.189: I/Process(10554): Sending signal. PID: 10554 SIG: 9
```

What is issue please some one help me to get me out of thus problem. Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: We need some more info.. line no: 491 in MainScreen.java

Comment: ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v;

Comment: I have post my answer. Just have a look. Problem is v is editText. You are trying to typecast it to ImageView. Just take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to typecast `EditText` to `ImageView` .

try this...

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.save_on_id);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.save_on);
    imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
```

and don't try to change ID's of `View`s. (You are assigning ID of `EditText` to `ImageView`)

Trimmed version of your code... try this

```
public void clickHandler(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.orderQty) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.save_on_id);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.save_on);
        imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please visit this link , After it you will get more explain.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570176/custom-baseadapter-edittext-click-and-update-database-in-button-click

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your suggestion is really appreciated , but unfortunately doesn't work for me. Please  see above thread  to help a person who are seeking this " HELP"

Answer (score 0):

Very complicated code.

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.orderQty) { // v is an instance of EditText
    int id = v.getId(); // Useless initialisation
    id = R.id.save_on_id;
    int rew = id; // Useless
    v.setId(id); // v is still an instance of EditText
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v; // java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
    //...
}
```

you'd better use the findViewById method

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public void clickHandler(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.orderQty) {
        System.out.println(" edit text click");
        System.out.println(" edit text id    dilshad : " + v.getId());
        int id = v.getId();
        id = R.id.save_on_id;
        System.out.println("save button id on button click     : " + id);
        int rew = id;
        v.setId(id);
        System.out.println("save button set  and get id      : "
        + v.getId());
        //hide edit text
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //show your image view
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.save_on_id);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.save_on);
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting same issue

Comment: yes... Please visit this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570176/custom-baseadapter-edittext-click-and-update-database-in-button-click

Comment: my answer is for normal work.. If you are using listView my answer is not correct...

Comment: Both questions are same? or different?

Comment: @saa..Quite same.. I just eliminate some part in this thread. This thread is little bit in easy language and more elaboration... Please some one help  me to resolve either of these question..

Comment: @saa... yes but still i am getting...problem in this thread ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570176/custom-baseadapter-edittext-click-and-update-database-in-button-click

Comment: What problem you are getting?

Comment: @BlueGreen: To be frank your posted question is very small issue. Try to practice listview with custom adapters concept. There are many tutorials, just google it. So you can solve your problem very easily..

Answer (score -3):

Use 
`View.VISIBLE`

instead of

`ImageView.VISIBLE`

Also

How do you click a `view` which is `invisible`

there is some logic issue there. The view that you tap is not the `ImageView` its and `EditText` . So within that

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.orderQty) {

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.save_on_id);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.save_on);
    imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: there is no difference between `View.VISIBLE` and `ImageView.VISIBLE` as `ImageView` is a subclass of `View`...

Comment: please read about the concepts of Inheritance in JAVA. and There is no constant with name `VISIBLE` in `ImageView`. `VISIBLE` constant is defined in `View`. then how can you say use `View.VISIBLE` instead of `ImageView.VISIBLE`?